# Mean of subset in nested dataframe (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have the following toy dataframe in R in which I'm attempting to take the mean of the true/false Value *within* Condition and Name.

```
Name  Condition  Values
1     A          True
1     B          False
1     A          True
2     B          True
2     B          False
3     A          False
4     A          True
4     B          True
...   ...        ...
```

Does anyone have advice on handling this nested structure? I'm new to R and am uncertain whether I need to use group_by or aggregate or something else. Many thanks!

Desired output:

```
Name  Condition  Values(mean)
1     A          1
1     B          0
2     A          0
2     B          0.5
3     A          0
3     B          0
4     A          1
4     B          1
...   ...        ...
```

Comment: `group_by` and `aggregate` do similar things from different libraries. Please give it a try and come back with specific issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group by 'Name', 'Condition' and the get the `mean` of a logical `vector` to create the 'Values' column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(Name, Condition) %>%
     mutate(Values = mean(Values == 'True'))  
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   Name, Condition [6]
#   Name Condition Values
#  <int> <chr>      <dbl>
#1     1 A            1  
#2     1 B            0  
#3     1 A            1  
#4     2 B            0.5
#5     2 B            0.5
#6     3 A            0  
#7     4 A            1  
#8     4 B            1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), Condition = c("A", 
"B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B"), Values = c("True", "False", 
"True", "True", "False", "False", "True", "True")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Data
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), Condition = c("A", 
"B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B"), Values = c("True", "False", 
"True", "True", "False", "False", "True", "True")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
#Code
library(dplyr)
#Mutate
df1 %>% mutate(Index=ifelse(Values=='True',1,0)) %>% group_by(Name,Condition) %>%
  summarise(Avg = mean(Index,na.rm=T))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Name [4]
   Name Condition   Avg
  <int> <chr>     <dbl>
1     1 A           1  
2     1 B           0  
3     2 B           0.5
4     3 A           0  
5     4 A           1  
6     4 B           1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `Values` column to logical and take `mean` of it for each `Name` and `Condition`. Using base R `aggregate` :

```
df$Values <- as.logical(df$Values)
aggregate(Values~Name + Condition, df, mean)

#  Name Condition Values
#1    1         A    1.0
#2    3         A    0.0
#3    4         A    1.0
#4    1         B    0.0
#5    2         B    0.5
#6    4         B    1.0
```